# How to get value from .gitlab-ci.yml file in vue app?

Tags: docker, vue.js, gitlab, continuous-integration, vite

I would like to have the following implementation for getting a variable from .gitlab-ci.yml file. And depending on the variable set in the CI on gitlab, apply styles for your application on vue 3. But I don't know how to create a chain to pass this name to the frontend.

gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  BRAND_NAME: "FIRST_NAME"
```

app.vue

```
console.log(BRAND_NAME)
```

---

Unfortunately, I don't even have any idea how to implement it. For assembly and deployment I use docker and vite.

Comment: Check env variables for VueJS.

Comment: That doesn't work. Turns out undefined.
BRAND_NAME: JSON.stringify(process.env.BRAND_NAME)

Comment: Tried that one? https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/05/28/vue-3-vite-access-environment-variables-from-dotenv-env

Comment: I recommend focusing on Vite alone, then try to do that in Docker. Step by step.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm trying but for now unsuccessfully